# Knight tour on $5 \times 5$ incongruence

Tags: hamiltonian-path, knight-tours, chessboard

I cannot seem to understand something, it has been puzzling me for days. There exist $304$ tours from a corner in a $5 \times 5$ board based on an exhaustive search algorithm. $304$ is a multiple of $19!!$ How is that possible?

I assume that we are talking about a tree-like search, when moving the knight several possibilities appear to move it further so you multiply the numbers, and then select the tours out of all possibilities.

If a knight can only move to seven squares normally (if it is not the first move or by lack of space). How can the $304$ tours be multiple of $19$? Where does it come from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a sum of possible passes and as result it can add to a number that is a multiple of 19.

Comment: $19!!$ is a very huge number, and does not divide $304$.

Comment: It would be a sum if we were talking about two separate squares to begin from. Strictly from a corner, the total should only be made out of products of the split ways.

Answer (score 1):

A 5x5 board is an extremely restricted space for knights. Only the centre square gives them their full move set (of $8$ options, not $7$).

The corners have a separate mini-tour which goes first or last (assume first for now). For the tour around the rest of the squares, there are options to use the centre square to reverse the remainder of the tour, plus the option to finish on the centre square. This gives the odd multiplier.

The two main tours:

[image]

These two circuits are linked via one of the non-corner squares on the red circuit, and the centre square can be inserted into the blue circuit at a number of points.

Comment: First of all, there are tours which depart from the square in between two corners (in mean the square you need to jump to).

Comment: Clarified in the answer, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @letFunny I would disagree that there are any tours that start on the non-corner squares of the red circuit. As you can see from counting the light and dark squares in my diagram, the tour has to start and end on a light square. In fact any tour has to either start or end on a corner; the red circuit can only be entered once.

Comment: Sorry, now that I have reread my comment I have realised it sounds confusing. By depart I meant start at the corner but then leave the red circuit to later come back to it.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean now. And that's where the complications set in; depending on exactly how you exit the red circuit, you may have sometimes 3, sometimes 4 option squares on the blue circuit to re-enter the red circuit to finish.